# how to add border around row in a table

Tags: jquery

i got a table which has fields in each row . if field is empty i want the particular row with red border around it.

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5" >
<tr>
<td class="cellformatting"><label>first name*</label></td>
<td class="cellformatting"><input id="fname" type="text" class="required searchfields" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="cellformatting"><label>last name*</label></td>
<td class="cellformatting"><input id="lname" type="text" class="searchfields" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i jst want the script if suppose last name is empty it should add some css around that particular row of table in which last name is shown.

Comment: I'm still sleepy, but can a row have a border?  I thought only `td`s could have borders...  **Edit**: nm, I guess I'm dumb.  Carry on.

Comment: @XyanEwing u r pretty right thats what i m trying to ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$(function(){

    checkBorder();

    $("table tr input").change(function(){
       checkBorder(); 
    });

});
function checkBorder(){
 $("table tr").each(function(){
    if ($(this).find("input").val() == ""){
       $(this).attr("class", "border");   
    }
});   
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kh6q8/

---

Here is a version which works without "Normalized CSS", but the `cell-spacing` had to be removed:

http://jsfiddle.net/kh6q8/2/

Comment: If you remove "Normalized CSS" in the jsfiddle your code does nothing.

Comment: @core1024 I've included a non-normalized css version

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
function check_empty(){
    $("td input").each(function(){
      if(this.value === ''){
         $(this).closest('tr').css('border', '1px solid red');
      }
    });
}
```

EDIT - i corrected it to work with inputs